# Group by column on basis of occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'User': ["alex", "alex", "ravi", "dodo", "dodo", "dodo", "cokie","dodo","nemo","ravi"],
    'Id': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c','a','e','b']
})
```

This is how my dataframe looklike:

```
    User Id
0   alex  a
1   alex  b
2   ravi  b
3   dodo  a
4   dodo  b
5   dodo  b
6  cokie  c
7   dodo  a
8   nemo  e
9   ravi  b
```

I first counted the no of items for each user using the following code:

```
df_group = df.groupby(['User', 'Id'])

# size of group to count observations
df_group = df_group.size()
  
# make a column name 
df_group = df_group.reset_index(name='Observation')
```

This is how it looks:

```
  User  Id Observation
0   alex    a   1
1   alex    b   1
2   cokie   c   1
3   dodo    a   2
4   dodo    b   2
5   nemo    e   1
6   ravi    b   2
```

I want to remove a user who is coming 1 time and also observation is 1. For example user nemo and cokie. But I don't want to remove user alex, even though items a and b are coming 1 time or user ravi.

How can I do it?

My end goal:

```
    User    Id Observation
0   alex    a   1
1   alex    b   1

3   dodo    a   2
4   dodo    b   2

6   ravi    b   2
```

Comment: including your Python code and output as executable JS/HTML snippets doesn't actually help. Removed all the snippet annotations.

Comment: Will you please manually edit Observation column in your outputted dataframe to be what you want to achieve? That way, we can understand your goal by comparing your current data with what you want to get, and we can rapidly provide solutions for you.

Comment: Done edit Observation column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```py
s = df.groupby('User').size() > 1
df = df.merge(df_group, how='left')[df['User'].isin(s[s].index)].drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it in an automated way I suggest to use a merge after using `.groupby(['User']).filter(lambda x: len(x)` to filter those Users that show up only once.

```
df_group = df.groupby(['User', 'Id'])

# size of group to count observations
df_group = df_group.size()
  
# make a column name 
df_group = df_group.reset_index(name='Observation').merge(df.groupby(['User']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)).drop_duplicates()
```

Which outputs:

```
   User Id  Observation
0  alex  a            1
1  alex  b            1
2  dodo  a            2
4  dodo  b            2
6  ravi  b            2
```

Alternatively without using `merge`:

```
df_group = df.groupby(['User', 'Id'],as_index=False)

# size of group to count observations
df_group = df_group.size()
  
# make a column name 
df_group = df_group.loc[df_group['User'].isin(df.groupby(['User']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['User'].unique())]
```

Comment: Hello @Celius! I have another question related with this problem. Your above code solves removing those rows where users who are coming 1 time and also observation is 1 are removed. If I want to remove Users who have 2 occurrence and for those occurrences observation is 1. How can I do this?